# how to pass a value to text box using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass a value to text box according to the birthdate, which user enters. If the user is less than 15 years `"Borrow Books"` field should have the value `4`, otherwise it should be `8`. Please advice me how to proceed.

Comment: Please don't use `<table>` to lay-out a form unless it's a form expressing tabular data, which this doesn't look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to add an event to the asp.net calender: Calendar.SelectionChanged Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Then your code will be something like this:

Front End:

```
 <asp:Calendar ID="calcBorrowerBorn" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Selection_Change" VisibleDate="2014-11-08" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" 
            Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="250px" 
            NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" ShowGridLines="True" Width="330px">
            <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" 
                Height="8pt" />
            <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="White" Height="12pt" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Calendar>
```

Back End:

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
         DateTime userSelectedDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
           txtBorrowerBooks.Text = (GetAge(userSelectedDate) > 15)?"8":"4";
  }

public Int32 GetAge(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;

    var a = (today.Year * 100 + today.Month) * 100 + today.Day;
    var b = (dateOfBirth.Year * 100 + dateOfBirth.Month) * 100 + dateOfBirth.Day;

    return (a - b) / 10000;
}
```

Comment: cannot immplicity convert type 'int' to 'string' im getting this to "txtBorrowerBooks.Text =year > 15 ? 8: 4;"

Comment: @shumz Oh....I added a double quotes to that

Comment: @shumz txtBorrowerBooks.Text = (GetAge(userSelectedDate) > 15)?"8":"4";

Answer (score 0):

Use `Selection_Change` event of calander as follows in your calender html write `OnSelectionChanged="Selection_Change"`

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DateTime date1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    var dateDiff=DateTime.Today-date1 ;
    var year=dateDiff.Year;
    var totalBook=year > 15 ? 8: 4;
    txtBorrowerBooks.Text =totalBook.ToString();

}
```

### Edit 1

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DateTime date1 = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
    DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    var dateDiff=DateTime.Today-date1 ;
    var year=(zeroTime +dateDiff).Year;
    var totalBook=year > 15 ? 8: 4;
    txtBorrowerBooks.Text =totalBook.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Șhȇkhaṝ : cannot immplicity convert type 'int' to 'string' im getting this to "txtBorrowerBooks.Text =year > 15 ? 8: 4;"

Comment: ok use Tostring method.

Comment: 'System.TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'System.TimeSpan' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?